# Why does the order of `buildTypes` matter?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running into a strange issue with gradle.

My `app/build.gradle` file has a section which looks like this:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
        beta {
            initWith release
            ...
        }
    }
```

When I run `./gradlew assembleBeta`, the output is `app-beta.apk`, which I can install on my device.

However, I want to change the order of my build types, purely for aesthetics. So it now looks like:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        beta {
            initWith release
            ...
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
```

This syncs fine, but when I run `./gradlew assembleBeta`, the output is now `app-beta-unsigned.apk`! And I cannot install this apk on a device - it tells me installation failed.

How is it possible that simply by changing the order in which my build types are declared, my apk can become broken?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the apk is broken after changing the order of build types is because, in this situation, gradle requires that the `release` build type is defined before the `beta` build type.

Why is this? It's because `beta` refers to `release` in the line: `initWith release`

If `release` is defined after `beta`, then the `initWith release` command will silently fail. This is because, at the point `initWith release` is run, `release` does not exist. Although it may seem like Gradle should be able to look-ahead to the definition of `release` later in the file, it cannot.

Then, when running `./gradlew assembleBeta`, the beta apk is built successfully - but the apk is unsigned - as alluded to by the name of the output file, `app-beta-unsigned.apk`. In the previous setup, `beta` was getting its `signingConfig` from `release`. When `initWith release` fails, the `beta` build simply has no `signingConfig` set - so the output apk is of course unsigned.